# Devise: Users not signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise to set up user authentication, but I'm having difficulty getting users to sign in.

The forms are rendering correctly for sign in and sign up. The problem is that when I click submit, I get a (No route matches "/sessions/user") error. If I go to the sign up form, fill in the fields, and submit, then I get the same error. However, when I go back to the root url (pages#home) the user is signed in. If I log out, and try to sign in with the same user credentials, I get the no route matches error and the user is not signed in at all.

I'd like to fix this so that sign up/sign in redirects to pages#home and the user gets signed in from the sign in form. Any ideas?

Please let me know if any additional info is needed, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What version of Rails and Devise are you using?  Also can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: Rails: 3.0.5, Devise 1.2.1, routes.rb http://min.us/mTTAspPGXiM8u#1 (lack rep to post images) Note: the match 'session/user' is commented out, but when uncommented I get a 'Could not find devise mapping for path "/sessions/user"' error. I appreciate your coding wisdom!

Comment: I'm a little confused regarding the purpose of the session and user paths that you are creating.  Are you trying to overwrite the devise code or are you just trying to add a little functionality to these methods?  If you just need to add a little functionality I would recommend extending the existing controllers, doing your code and then calling super so devise can do its thing.  Also not sure what effect this will have but convention says to have root to at the end of your routes file (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root).

Comment: I'm using the rails 3 hartl code as a framework (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:sessions_controller) which has a sessions controller + helper (controller is commented out, kept a few helper functions). Not trying to overwrite devise at this point, just want to sign users in through it. i find it very odd that after registration a new user is signed in, but the sign in form itself is not signing users in. Please post any other suggestions you may have and in the mean time I will keep plugging away at it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old sessions controller, deleted it, restarted server. Then I got a 'BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in Devise/sessionsController#create' error on sign in, which relates to an empty encrypted_password db column. I looked at the user model and commented out attr_accessor :password and created a new user, the encrypted_password for that user was saved, and sign in now works. Hooray!!